# Observable Collection and System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, observablecollection

I got the screen with listbox(listbox takes items from observable collection), where the user can choose item.

this is the code which shows what happens when the user click on the item:

```
 // method is invoked when we select the element from the list 
        private void ItemsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // getting object which was clicked in the listbox
            dbFoodTable item = Fooditems.ElementAt(ItemsList.SelectedIndex);
            // mark this object as choosenMeal and store it to get it back in next page
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["choosen"] = item;
            //going to next page
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Customization.xaml", UriKind.Relative));            
       }
```

When I choose the item from listbox I go to next screen where I have all details of this item(like prize, description, name ...), the error shows when I'm backing to this listbox screen.

this line

```
 dbFoodTable item = Fooditems.ElementAt(ItemsList.SelectedIndex);
```

is underlined with this info An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. This line is in the

```
ItemsList_SelectionChanged
```

method.

It would be perfect if this method wouldn't be even invoked, when I'm backing, but world isn't perfect. 
I think it works in this way, when we go to other page we selected for example second item and when we backing to this screen this item is not selected any more => selectionchanged => invoking method

How I should solve this problem ?

Comment: I suspect that the `ListBox` doesn't have anything selected, and therefore `SelectedIndex` is -1. Simply check for this in a conditional and don't execute your code.

Comment: yeah, of course I should do this with if statement.. thx for help, write it as answer and I would accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make sure that the selectedIndex exists in the list with an "if statement"?

Comment: thx for answer, yeah I check with "if statement" that the selectedInex isn't -1 and it works

Comment: why isn't that in your post?  Isn't that where the exception is being thrown?  Why aren't you checking the index there?

Comment: because I make it after your answer and comment of Steve, earlier my code looked like this in post :)

Comment: and it still crashes there?

Comment: no, after adding if(itemList.SelectedIndex != -1) everything works.

Comment: you're welcome, cause it helps me a little bit and steve didn't create the answer

Comment: i see, i didn't read the comments.   oh well, I gave same answer thx